# Solving the differential equation $x'' + 5x' + 4x = e^{-t}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am asked to solve the following differential equation:

> $x'' + 5x' + 4x = e^{-t}$

The procedures I follow are:

1- Find the general solution. For that,

\begin{align*}
r^2+5r+4 &= 0\\
(r+1)(r+4) &= 0\\
\\
y_g &= c_1 e^{-t} + c_2 e^{-4t}
\end{align*}

2- Find the particular solution.

When doing that I called the particular solution $y_p = Ae^{-t}$, which means that $y_p' = - A e^{-t}$ and $y_p''= Ae^{-t}$. When inserting those on the given differential equation, that produces

\begin{align*}
Ae^{-t} - 5 Ae^{-t} + 4 Ae^{-t} &= e^{-t}\\
0 &= e^{-t}
\end{align*}

Where am I off here? Should I have called my particular solution something else?

Thank you.

**Wolfram Alpha's output:** [link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%27%2B5y%27%2B4y%3De%5E(-x))

Comment: Your particular solution should be $Ate^{-t}$

Comment: Why is that eepperly16?

Comment: Because $e^{-t}$ already is in your homogenous solution, you need to try a term with $te^{-t}$.

Comment: @eepperly16 so I need to try to use that strategy everytime the right-handside of the nonhomogeneous equation is equal to one of my solutions for the homogeneous equation? Or only when it leads me nowhere?

Comment: @bru1987 You can use Laplace transform

Comment: @bru1987 Every time. Suppose your guess for the particular solution is some $f(t)$, which is also a term in the homogenous solution. Then, *by the definition of the homogeneous solution*, you will get 0 on LHS of the equation when $Af(t)$ is plugged in. Thus, $Af(t)$ will not satisfy the equation, and $Atf(t)$ must be tried.

Comment: Ah I see eepperly. Thank you for explaining, best regards!

Answer (score 1):

To solve:

$$x''(t)+5x(t)+4x(t)=e^{-t}$$

Use Laplace transform:

$$\mathcal{L}_t\left[x''(t)\right]_{\text{s}}+5\cdot\mathcal{L}_t\left[x'(t)\right]_{\text{s}}+4\cdot\mathcal{L}_t\left[x(t)\right]_{\text{s}}=\mathcal{L}_t\left[e^{-t}\right]_{\text{s}}$$

Now use:

1. $$\mathcal{L}_t\left[x''(t)\right]_{\text{s}}=\text{s}^2\text{X}(\text{s})-\text{s}x(0)-x'(0)$$
2. $$\mathcal{L}_t\left[x'(t)\right]_{\text{s}}=\text{s}\text{X}(\text{s})-x(0)$$
3. $$\mathcal{L}_t\left[x(t)\right]_{\text{s}}=\text{X}(\text{s})$$
4. $$\mathcal{L}_t\left[e^{-t}\right]_{\text{s}}=\frac{1}{1+\text{s}}$$

So, we get:

$$\text{s}^2\text{X}(\text{s})-\text{s}x(0)-x'(0)+5\cdot\left(\text{s}\text{X}(\text{s})-x(0)\right)+4\text{X}(\text{s})=\frac{1}{1+\text{s}}$$

Solving $\text{X}(\text{s})$:

$$\text{X}(\text{s})=\frac{1+x(0)(\text{s}^2+6\text{s}+5)+x'(0)(1+\text{s})}{(1+\text{s})^2(\text{s}+4)}$$

With inverse Laplace transform, we find:

$$x(t)=\frac{e^{-4t}\left(1-3x(0)-3x'(0)+e^{3t}\left(3t+12x(0)+3x'(0)-1\right)\right)}{9}$$

Comment: Surely this is overkill for what can be solved with just the method of undetermined coefficients?

Answer (score 1):

If $P(D) = (D+1)(D+4)$ the particular solution will be

$$ y_{p} = \frac{te^{-t}}{P(-1)}$$

To see why recall the exponential shift rule for the differentiation operator:

$$ P(D)e^{at}u(t) = e^{at}P(D+a)u(t)$$

where $u(t)$ is some function of $t$

Hence,

$$ (D+1)(D+4)e^{-t}t = e^{-t}D(D+3)t = 3e^{-t} $$

We almost obtain $e^{-t}$ in the right hand side.

Now note that if $P(D) = (D+1)(D+4)$

$$ P'(D) = (D+1)+(D+4)$$

If we evaluate in $D=-1$

$$ P'(-1) = 3$$

So

$$ (D+1)(D+4)\frac{e^{-t}t}{P'(-1)} = \frac{e^{-t}}{3} D(D+3)t = e^{-t} $$

So our particular solution will be

$$ y_{p} = \frac{te^{-t}}{3}$$

In general for

$$ y'' + Ay' + By = e^{ax} \quad \textrm{ and } P(a) =0 $$
we have the particular solution

$$ y_{p} = \frac{te^{at}}{P'(a)} \quad P'(a) \neq 0 $$